# How do I keep Vista from killing my program on exceptions?

Tags: delphi, exception, windows-vista

It used to be that if an exception got raised and propagated far enough up the call stack, Application's main loop  would handle it and give you a dialog box.  That behavior seems to be broken under Windows Vista.  If any exception reaches that level, Vista steps in and says the program "has stopped working," when it used to be perfectly able to continue under XP.  (That's the entire reason the exception handler in the main loop is there, for heaven's sake!)

Is there any way to fix this?  Preferably in my code itself and not just on my computer, so it won't screw up on other systems?

Comment: mmmm...using try..catch blocks and log your errors using NLog or Log4Net in a text file ???

Comment: Replacing the Application.OnException event with your own is not that difficult to do, plus you can log the exception to a file at that point as well.

Comment: Yeah, but I'd prefer not to have to set that up every time I hack up some little tool for personal use.

Comment: How did JITEnable get set in the first place? I thought it defaulted to 0

Comment: question should have a .net tag?

Comment: Mjustin: Nope.  Jim: No idea.  I didn't even know it existed.  But that was the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check to ensure that the global variable in System, JITEnable is still set to 0. If that variable is set to 1, hardware (and external) exceptions will cause that behavior by calling UnhandledExceptionFilter. If it is set to 2, **any** exception will cause it.

Comment: @Mason: How did JITEnable get set in the first place?  I thought it defaulted to 0.

Answer (score 1):

You should add an application level exception handler, http://www.chami.com/tips/delphi/011497D.html.  Also you should look into running madexcept to determine why these exceptions are happening, so they can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not all exceptions were nicely caught, even in XP. Ever had an application just vanish, ot just hanging and needing a pskill? (some Delphi version anyone?)
I would try to plug EurekaLog in your app and see if it gives some information on what happens.